# How to insert Multilingual data in database using JSP?

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, localization, internationalization

I'm setting up a web application to store multilingual data in DB through JSP,I have tried changing charset to UTF-8 it doesn't work. My Tables are in correct configuration only (nvarchar), I'm a beginner in programming though I didn't get relevant examples over internet. Can anybody help me to sort it out. Thanks in advance
My controller code:

```
package com.suth.DbConnectiviti;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String name = request.getParameter("fullname");
    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    String addr = request.getParameter("address");
    String age = request.getParameter("age");
    String qual = request.getParameter("qual");
    String percent = request.getParameter("percentage");
    String year = request.getParameter("yop");
    if(name.isEmpty()||addr.isEmpty()||age.isEmpty()||qual.isEmpty()||percent.isEmpty()||year.isEmpty())
    {
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        out.println("<font color=red>Please fill all the fields</font>");
        rd.include(request, response);
    }
    else
    {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
     // loads driver
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://****;databaseName=***?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "****", "****!");

    PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("insert into student1 values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    ps.setString(1, name);
    ps.setString(2, userName);
    ps.setString(3, pass);
    ps.setString(4, addr);
    ps.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(age));
    ps.setString(6, qual);
    ps.setString(7, percent);
    ps.setString(8, year);


    ps.executeUpdate(); // execute it on test database
    System.out.println("successfuly inserted");
    ps.close();
    c.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("error.html");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

}
}

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
   <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Guru Registration Form</title>
  </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Guru Register Form</h1>
   <form action="LoginController" method="post">
        <table style="with: 50%">
            <tr>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fullname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="userName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>UserName</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="pass" /></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="address" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="age" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Contact No</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="qual" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Percentage</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="percentage" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Year Passed</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="yop" /></td>
            </tr></table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
```

`

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support UTF-8 (not until SQL Server 2019 anyway, and that's still currently in preview). I suspect the problem here is you have a string (literal) that is declared as a `varchar`, not an `nvarchar`. Without the code this is impossible to know. Paste the code you're using to insert your values, and explain why it's not working (show the results your getting for example). Then the volunteers here can actually help you. Otherwise tehre's little we can do other than guess. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have added my code, Please look into it. Or please give me some relevant sample codes to achieve multilingual insertion